# How to use streambuilder for manage state of two different types user and navigate them into different screen base on there user type

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

my application have two types of users one is Service provider & Service Seekers I have to manage state of Two different types of user using steam builder in flutter

my application have two types of users one is Service provider & Service Seekers I have to manage state of Two different types of user using stream-builder in flutter. and base on the user type I want to show them different screen. I create a code where I can manage only one state of user I not able to manage second type of user please help!

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrkl6.png)

Comment: Going forward, please don't post the same question multiple times. At best, the duplicates will be closed, but it may actualy get you banned from the site. Instead, if you have additio al information to share, you can add that to the original post by click the tiny `edit` link under it.

Comment: Alsp: please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Where do you keep track of the user type? In your database?

Comment: No .I want to track user so they navigate different screens base on there user type

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.